# How to internationalize the specific text message in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

Currently I'm implementing a service for sending notifications (SMS, for example) to customers. Service is written in Java, based on Spring Boot.

I'd like to send a message in the recipient's language.

So basically I'd like to have a method, taking some id of the message with the desired localization ("en", "fr", "es") and giving back the correct String. Also configuring some default language (like "en") would be great - to fall back to it if the desired language is not supported.

Any suggestions how to achieve this with Spring Boot?

P.S.: Sorry, yes, I've tried "googling". I've found several internationalization examples, but most of them seem not useful, as they're intended for the whole user interface, not a specific message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to create a couple resource files. Put a file called `messages_en.properties` and another called `messages_fr.properties` in `src/main/resources`.

In the en file put a line:

```
hello.world=Hello World!
```

In the fr file put a line:

```
hello.world=Bonjour le monde!
```

Then where ever you need to get this text inject a MessageSource

```
@Autowired private MessageSource messageSource;
```

Then you can use it to get the text

```
messageSource.getMessage("hello.world", null, locale);
```

You'll need to pass in the locale of the user to that method. You can setup a LocaleResolver to do that if you need.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately I haven't succeed yet. Is there any specific dependency and/or annotation to add?

Comment: In my case parentMessageSource is null - now searching how to initialize it properly.

Comment: @stepio Add to your custom class the `@Service` or `@Component` annotation

Answer (score 0):

As of now I've resolved the issue initializing MessageSource manually:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initMessageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    reloadableMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    reloadableMessageSource.setBasename(config.getI18nBundleBase());
    reloadableMessageSource.setCacheSeconds(config.getI18nCacheSeconds());
    this.messageSource = reloadableMessageSource;
}
```

Autowiring initialized my messageSource with empty DelegatingMessageSource, so internationalization did not work.